# Getting data in view of the entity

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have such a link:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="XID,YID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="page.aspx?i={0}&f={1}"/>
```

`XID` and `YID` are taken from an entity that is automatically loaded from the database

I would like to replace `YID` with `YUUID`

`YUUID` would be defined in the code (dependent on `YID`)

`YUUID` is not in the same table so I do not have access to the field

Overall, I would like to have as below. I do not know how to do it to access `YUUID`

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="XID,YUUID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="page.aspx?i={0}&f={1}"/>
```

Comment: You've a couple of options, mainly: code-behind or scriptlets to replace the ID's XID/YID using `runat="server"` or `<% some object property %>`

Comment: @UK_Dev `DataNavigateUrlFormatString="<%page.aspx?i={0}&f=YUUID%>"` How should it look like?

Comment: Replace the ID that was previously there with the scriptlet of what you want there, or just outright replace it - I'm slightly confused as to why this isn't a straight forward replace the ID error

Comment: @UK_Dev `<a href="page.aspx?i=1&f=<%#Eval('YUUID')%>`I get it when I change it. It does not collect data. And when I build it differently, I have a mistake `Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event. System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLinkField does not have a DataBinding event.`